# special character in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I am querying the Hive tables for partitions 
show partitions  I am getting special character in one of the partition date "date_created=2016-12-%2A"

I tried dropping this partition as well through  the command 
alter table  DROP PARTITION (date_created='2016-12-%2A');
But no luck, can some one please suggest what can be done here>
Thanks In advance

Comment: Have you never seen that kind of "%xx" stuff in URLs?? Hexadecimal 2A is decimal 42 is character `*` (just connect to http://www.urlencoder.org/ and try to encode `2016-12-*`) and since you cannot put a star in path names, Hive has to encode it...

Comment: As a side note, this means that your so-called *"date_created"* column is just a garbage dump of random text. That might be more important to fix it than to try to hide the consequences by dropping the partition.

Comment: You may also be able to use `RLIKE` and escape the % character: `alter table <your table> drop partition (date_created rlike '2016-12-\%2A')`.  Regex is not my friend, so test that carefully.